# Menu with sticky CSS property causes pop-up to be out of position with X Y offset

Tags: html, css

I have created a contenteditable div that has a sticky menu toolbar (sticks at top of browser if scrolling reaches top of page) and a content area with text and an image.  Clicking the image brings up a pop-up toolbox to allow for image manipulation.

The pop-up toolbox is supposed to appear next to the cursor pointer, hower:

1. With the CSS sticky configuration it does NOT work - it is offset by over 100 pixels in both X and Y and gets more/less offset when at different page zoom factors.
2. When I remove the sticky configuration (position:sticky, top:0), it works and pops up right at the cursor pointer

Why does this happen? How can I keep the sticky menu toolbar and have it work as intended?

Code below:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style>

 /* EDITOR */
.qr_editor {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 2rem;
}

/* TOOLBAR */
.qr_editor .toolbar {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
  z-index:10;
  
  /*when this sticky part is removed, the pop-up toolbar pops up in the right place*/
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

</style>
<div id="position"></div>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="qr_editor">
        <div class="toolbar sticky">
            <div class="line">
                <span class="box">
                    <span>Example Sticky Tool Bar Goes Here</span>                      
                </span>
                <div class="box" id="popup_toolbar" style="display:none;background-color:white;border:solid black;">
                        Sample Image Tools Popup Box
                </div>   
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-area">
            <div contenteditable="true">
                <div>Sample Text</div>
                <img class="qr_editor_img"  src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png" style="width:100%;cursor:pointer">
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //to display coordinates
    $( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
        $( "#position" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY );
    });

    //pops up toolbar for image manipulation
    var img_src = '';
    $(document).on("click", "img", function(e) {   
        console.log(e.pageX);
        console.log(e.pageY);
        //position the popup toolbar where the mouse click is
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#popup_toolbar').css( 'position', 'absolute' );
        $('#popup_toolbar').css( 'top', e.pageY );
        $('#popup_toolbar').css( 'left', e.pageX );
        $('#popup_toolbar').show();
    }); 
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you are missing "An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed)." so it is relative to parent. Do you want to change  $('#popup_toolbar').css( 'position', 'absolute' ); to  $('#popup_toolbar').css( 'position', 'fixed' );

Comment: tried it and that works ^

Comment: Follow up problem - if I add some text above the image to make it long enough to scroll, then click the image, the toolbar pops up correctly at the cursor.  Scroll the page, click again, the toolbar is now offset NOT at the cursor...  any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style>

 /* EDITOR */
.qr_editor {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 2rem;
}

/* TOOLBAR */
.qr_editor .toolbar {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
  z-index:10;
  
  /*when this sticky part is removed, the pop-up toolbar pops up in the right place*/
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#popup_toolbar {
  position: fixed;
}

</style>
<div id="position"></div>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="qr_editor">
        <div class="toolbar sticky">
            <div class="line">
                <span class="box">
                    <span>Example Sticky Tool Bar Goes Here</span>                      
                </span>
                <div class="box" id="popup_toolbar" style="display:none;background-color:white;border:solid black;">
                        Sample Image Tools Popup Box
                </div>   
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-area">
            <div contenteditable="true">
                <div>Sample Text</div>
                <img class="qr_editor_img"  src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png" style="width:100%;cursor:pointer">
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //to display coordinates
    $( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
        $( "#position" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY );
    });

    //pops up toolbar for image manipulation
    var img_src = '';
    $(document).on("click", "img", function(e) {   
        console.log(e.pageX);
        console.log(e.pageY);
        //position the popup toolbar where the mouse click is
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#popup_toolbar').css( 'top', e.pageY );
        $('#popup_toolbar').css( 'left', e.pageX );
        $('#popup_toolbar').show();
    }); 
});
</script>
</body>
```